# How do I make a Theorem n followed by a Theorem n' ?

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am writing a paper where I have a stated a theorem, and then a short time later I state another theorem which is equivalent to the first. Is it possible to number them so that the second is a primed version of the first? In other words, if the first gets numbered as Theorem 7, I would like its equivalent version to be numbered as Theorem 7'. Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{thmbis}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\thethm}{\ref{#1}$'$}%
   \addtocounter{thm}{-1}%
   \begin{thm}}
  {\end{thm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
$1+1=2$
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}\label{comm}
$a+b=b+a$
\end{thm}
\begin{thmbis}{comm}
$x+y=y+x$
\end{thmbis}
\begin{thm}
$0\ne0$
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

In this way the "primed" theorem doesn't need to be near the main one. The `thmbis` environment takes as argument the label given to the main one.

If the "primed" theorem is always immediately after the main one, you can say

```
\newenvironment{thmbis}
  {\addtocounter{thm}{-1}%
   \renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}$'$}%
   \begin{thm}}
  {\end{thm}}
```

If **hyperref** is used, one has to hack its automatic mechanism for creating hyperlinks; the following seems to work:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\neutralize}[1]{\expandafter\let\csname c@#1\endcsname\count@}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newenvironment{thmbis}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\thethm}{\ref{#1}$'$}%
   \neutralize{thm}\phantomsection
   \begin{thm}}
  {\end{thm}}
```

Use `\ref*{#1}` if you don't want to make a link pointing to the "main theorem".

Comment: Would `^\prime` not be better than `'` for "priming"?

Comment: it's a bad idea to use `\addtocounter{thm}{-1}` as it doesn't work well with `hyperref`. Here, in your second example, if you use the \label/ref mechanism to refer to the primed theorem, the hyperlink will go to the wrong place (the unprimed theorem).

Comment: @Seamus: $'$ and $^\prime$ are equivalent.

Comment: Is there any chance to have this or one of the like solutions have hyperref jump to the primed theorem (and not the original one)?

Comment: What is the difference between `\ref` and `\ref*`?

Comment: @Stephen The latter is defined when `hyperref` is loaded and doesn’t make a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

An idea but ... finally I undelete

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newcounter{biscompt}

\newtheorem{bis}[biscompt]{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thebiscompt}{% 
\setcounter{biscompt}{\thetheo} 
\arabic{theo}'}
\usepackage{hyperref}   

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

\section{}  
\begin{theo}
On vérifie que :  $1\not= 1$
\end{theo}

\newpage
\section{}
\begin{theo}
On vérifie que :  $2\not= 3$
\end{theo}

\newpage   
\section{}   



\begin{theo}
On vérifie que :  $1\not= 1$
\end{theo}

\begin{bis}\label{bis}
On vérifie que :  $1\not= 1$
\end{bis}

\newpage
\section{}

With \ref{bis} 
\end{document}
```