# Manual numbering of Theorems

Tags: numbering, theorems

I have a setup where theorems are numbered automatically. Now I want a single theorem be numbered with special number, e.g. after Theorem 2 write Theorem 2'. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't comment yet so if some that can change this answer to a comment sees it feel free to do so.

I believe your question is a possible duplicate of [How do I make a Theorem n followed by a Theorem n' ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21506/how-do-i-make-a-theorem-n-followed-by-a-theorem-n).

You should see if this question also answers yours

Comment: It looks good but I've thought that exists easier solution...

Comment: @VolodymyrBodenchuk From my own experience in dealing with latex the assumption is that you spend most of your effort adding content and let LaTeX take care of the typesetting part. This is by design, you're not supposed to be handling that level of layout detail, that's the whole point.  Often times I find things LaTeX does that I don't like and I seek out a way to force a different behavior.  The great thing about LaTeX is that it's flexible enough to be changed, but because LaTeX does some complicated things under the hood it is not necessarily changeable in a user friendly way.