# How do I number an assumption with a prime (')?

Tags: numbering, theorems

I would like to number assumptions in my document as

> **Assumption 1.** Something.
>
> **Assumption 2.** Something else.
>
> **Assumption 2'.** An alternative to Assumption 2.
>
> **Assumption 3.** Some other thing.

and be able to reference Assumption 2' with the prime (') displayed (i.e., "By Assumption 2', we have...". May I know how I do this? I am using the [`informs3` document class](https://www.informs.org/content/download/317584/3012813/file/Management-Science-template.zip), which implements the `amsmath`, `amssymb`, and `theorem` packages, among others.

Comment: Maybe the post [How do I make a Theorem n followed by a  Theorem n'?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21506/110998) helps.

Comment: @gernot Tremendously. It solves my problem. Thanks!