# Conditions with primes in numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems

I have two very similar conditions, so I would like to have them be labeled Condition 3 and Condition 3' (or whatever number it happens to be). They do not appear one directly after the other in the document, in case that affects anything. I have a Condition environment defined via

```
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
```

but I don't know how to get one to copy the number of the other and insert `a '`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21511

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)