How to numerate theorem "Threorem 2' "?
I need to copy the text from the textbook, which contains the theorems in this order
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}

\newtheorem{dost_sys}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{dost_sys}
Theorem 1
\end{dost_sys}

\begin{dost_sys}
Theorem 2
\end{dost_sys}

\begin{dost_sys}
Theorem 2'
\end{dost_sys}

\end{document}

The last theorem starts with Theorem 2'

How did they manage to number the theorem 2'?

Please post a complete, compilable example, including the definition of the dost_sys environment. Otherwise, we havne't a clue!

@murray I apologize, I changed it.

duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21506/208544

@mbert Yes, I saw it. But it doesn't work. Command \thethm undefined. I often see this command in the answers, but these questions were many years ago. Is it outdated? What has it been changed to? Does it depend on the compiler? I use TeXworks.

I understood, thanks

@mbert Yes. Thank you!
